# How to output only words that are 3 letters or more using nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, cpu-word

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(fileName)
raw = f.read()


tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

this leaves out punctuation, and only keeps words 
    print(tokenizer.tokenize(raw))//this prints all words
    print(sent_tokenize(raw))

```
print('number of sentences equal',len(sent_tokenize(raw)))
print('number of words equal',len(tokenizer.tokenize(raw)))


average =(len(tokenizer.tokenize(raw))/len(sent_tokenize(raw)))
print('average word per senetnces eqauls',average)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @bkm answer pointed out you can use this:

```
long_words = [wrd for wrd in tokenizer.tokenize(raw) if len(wrd) >= 3]
```

But if what you want is to remove words like "and", "an", "if", "the", etc. you should filter them as stopwords:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

sw = stopwords.words('english')
# sw will contain a list of stopwords (and, the, unless, about, etc.)
# filter them out like this:
tokens = [t for t in tokenizer.tokenize(raw) if t not in sw]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for something like

```
long_words = [wrd for wrd in tokenizer.tokenize(raw) if len(wrd) > 2]
```

If you find multi-line for loops easier to follow the list comprehension above is equivalent to:

```
long_words = []
for wrd in tokenizer.tokenize(raw):
    if len(wrd) > 2:
        long_words.append(wrd)
```

If you're looking for 3 letters or more in a precise sense (ie not numbers) then the if clause can be:

```
len([chr for chr in wrd if chr.isalpha()]) > 2
```

And finally, if you only want to capture words with 3 or more characters then you can change `r'r\w+'` to `r'\w{3,}'`